# How to improve supersampling screenshots in designer's portfolio

Tags: portfolio, screenshot, presentation

Look at iMac mockups [on this page](http://www.behance.net/gallery/Planetaru-redesign/11838633.).

Quality of skewed screenshots placed in the mockups are poor. Seems like photoshop knows too little about super-sampling.

I know how to render a 3d model in 3dsmax with good supersampling, but it's a much more tedious work. **How can I make screenshots look good in photoshop?** 3D layers? Maybe vanishing point? Smart-objects seem to be rendered poorly, very bad supersampling I mean.

Comment: supersampling at its simplest is achieved by rendering with *at least* double the desired end resolution and then downsampling. Try starting with screen captures that are twice the pixel dimensions you plan on using in the final product. Also, as I understand it, if you can do your perspective/distort + scale in a single step, you will have a better result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the perspective which is inconsistent in your link, not the screenshots specifically. This seems more prevalent in the lower 3/4 screenshot. There's no attention to the existing iMac perspective, only the top edge angle.

[image]

**Vanishing point** would certainly help this.

There are many tutorials for Vanishing Point. And the entire point of the Vanishing Point filter is to match perspective of an existing photo.

Adobe Help: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e153d0941004907be29-7ff5a.html

PSD Tuts: http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/photo-effects-tutorials/getting-to-grips-with-the-vanishing-point-filter/

Photoshop.com: http://www.photoshop.com/tutorials?keywords=vanishing+point

I don't think you need actual 3D.

Comment: You know how to make precise perspective? I tried vanishing point but it gave similar results.

Answer (score 1):

How Photoshop interpolates an image when scaling is affected by the current default setting in `Image > Image Size...`. With CS6 and CC, leaving it on "Automatic" usually works adequately, but if you're not getting the result you want, try changing it to something explicit, such as Bicubic Sharper.

Since you're familiar with 3D, try `3D > New 3D Mesh from Layer > Postcard` and see if that doesn't give you a better result.